# Send Custom Post Notification to Followers

Tags: email, publish, php

I am trying to modify the function below (which works great for me ) to notify author followers that the author has published a new post, but I seem to be going round in circles.

```
function wcs_send_mail_on_publish_category_posts( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {

    global $post;

    if ( 'publish' !== $new_status or 'publish' === $old_status or 'logos' !== get_post_type( $post )  ) return;

        $subscribers = get_users( array ( 'role' => 'editor' ) );
        $emails      = array ();

        foreach ( $subscribers as $subscriber )
            $emails[] = $subscriber->user_email;

        $body = sprintf( 'Hey there is a new entry! See <%s>', get_permalink( $post )  );

        wp_mail( $emails, 'New entry!', $body );
}

add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'wcs_send_mail_on_publish_category_posts', 10, 3 );
```

This is what I have so far, in the example below I have several followers, but it only it only appears to send an email to the last email address created by the foreach loop.

```
function send_mail_on_publish_to_followers( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {

    global $post;
    global $bp;

    if ( 'publish' !== $new_status or 'publish' === $old_status or 'logos' !== get_post_type( $post )  ) return;

    $temp_post = get_post($post_id);
    $user_id = $temp_post->post_author;
    if ( $following = bp_get_follower_ids( array( 'user_id' => $user_id ) ) )

        $subscribers =explode(",", $following );
        $emails      = array ();

        foreach ( $subscribers as $subscriber )
            $user_info = get_userdata($subscriber);
            $emails[] = $user_info ->user_email;

        $body = sprintf( 'Hey there is a new entry! See <%s>', get_permalink( $post )  );

        wp_mail( $emails, 'New entry!', $body );
}

add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'send_mail_on_publish_to_followers', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: You need to enclose the `foreach ( $subscribers as $subscriber )` block in curly brackets, eg `foreach ( $subscribers as $subscriber ) { $user_info = get_userdata($subscriber); $emails[] = $user_info ->user_email; }`

Comment: Thank you bonger cymeta that works, sorry for the delay in answering was watching for an email to let me know someone had replied.